# Event Listner not working in .ejs file nodejs

Tags: node.js, click, ejs, eventemitter

[enter image description [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpaPZ.png)here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPmOZ.png)

## Heading

i want to add event listner for my project .but in my case iam using .ejs in nodejs
its not working anyone can help???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLda4.png)

try to fix my problem